# How can i solve the error (25.13) of Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: mongodb, android-studio

This is what appears when I try to compile the App.

I'm trying to use MongoDB Stitch and put in build.grandle(Project test) the following:

```
maven {
    url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
}
```

Looking like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also in build.grandle(Module app) I put the code:

```
compile 'org.mongodb:stitch:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

In the dependencies looking like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hasslerisaac.ruffy"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'org.mongodb:stitch:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

**Error**

> Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: org.mongodb:stitch:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
>       Show in Filw
>       Show in Project Structure Dialog

All this as shown in the MongoDB page to join the Stitch application of the Cluster to the application. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `stitch 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` dependency is not in maven central. This is usually the case for `SNAPSHOT` versions of maven packages.

When I look at the [github page](https://github.com/mongodb/stitch-android-sdk) of the stitch project I can see that they have what's called a snapshot repository for this package.

As per their suggestion, please add the snapshot repository and the package should resolve just fine:

```
repositories {
    // TODO: Remove once BSON 3.5.0 is released
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
}
```